# How to recursively expand cmake generator expressions?

Tags: cmake

I am using a cmake generator expression to read a target property

```
set_tests_properties(
    Java-wrapper
PROPERTIES
    ENVIRONMENT _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.library.path=$<TARGET_PROPERTY:ktx-jni,LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY>
)
```

`LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` is itself defined using a generator expression

```
set_target_properties(ktx-jni PROPERTIES
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${KTX_BUILD_DIR}/$<CONFIG>
)
```

During build `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` is expanded correctly and the built library appears in `Debug` or `Release` as expected. However in the environment seen by the test `$<CONFIG>` is not expanded.

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.library.path=/Users/mark/Projects/khronos/github/KTX-Software/build/macos/$<CONFIG>
```

If instead I use

```
ENVIRONMENT _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.library.path=${KTX_BUILD_DIR}/$<CONFIG>
```

`$<CONFIG>` is expanded correctly and the test runs successfully.

How can I get cmake to recursively expand `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, use `TARGET_GENEX_EVAL`, as in the below.

```
    ENVIRONMENT _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.library.path=$<TARGET_GENEX_EVAL:ktx-jni,$<TARGET_PROPERTY:ktx-jni,LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY>>
```

I missed it before because it is listed under *String Transformations* not *Target Dependent Queries* in the cmake documentation.